# Android save state of buttons in grid

Tags: android, button, grid, savestate

I have 2 questions:

1st) How can i choose that specific button of the grid, because the way i implemented it always chooses the first button even if i click on another button.

2nd) After implemeting poiint "1" I would like to show the available products to the user that would be shown with a green background color. If the user clicks on the button the backgroundcolor would change to red. The problem is that if i change activity and then come back again the color will be the default one, i.e, green. I want the activity to save the states of these buttons in order to reload as the user left them.

Below is the code:

```
    public class ShowList extends AppCompatActivity {

       ...(some methods that aren't relevant)

   //Here i'm retrieving objects from a database table and adding them to a List which will add items to a Grid using GridViewAdapter (class shown below)
    public void addItemsToGridListView(String tableName) {

            productsGridView.clear();

            Cursor res = db.getFromSpecificTAble(tableName);

            while(res.moveToNext()) {

                String productName = res.getString(0);
                String productPrice = res.getString(1);
                String buyType = res.getString(2);
                String productQuantity = res.getString(3);
                Product p = new Product(productName, productPrice);p.setBuyType(buyType);p.setProductQuantity(productQuantity);
                productsGridView.add(p);
            }

        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this,productsGridView );

        view = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);

        view.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

//Here is the button event to change the backgroundcolor
         public void goToBin(View v) {

```
            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.textViewList1);

            b.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}


public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private  ArrayList<Product> products;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {

        this.products = products;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return products.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        Button productName;
        TextView productPrice;
        TextView buyType;
        TextView productQuantity;
        ImageButton removeProduct;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null || (convertView.getTag() == null)) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_values, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.productName = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewList1);
            holder.productPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.EditTextList2);
            holder.buyType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewList3);
            holder.productQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewList4);
            holder.removeProduct = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.removeProduct);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.productName.setText(products.get(position).getProductName());
        holder.productPrice.setText(String.valueOf(products.get(position).getProductPrice()) + " €");
        holder.buyType.setText(products.get(position).getBuyType());
        holder.productQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(products.get(position).getProductQuantity()) + " Un.");
        holder.removeProduct.setTag(new Integer(position));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

When i start the activity it will be like this:

[image]

When i click on 1 button :

[image]

But when i leave that actitvity and come back to this one the buttons will be all green... instead of saving the ones that i previously changed the color to red.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try these : 
 1. Modify ***ShowList.java***

```
SharedPreferences pref_restore = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int position = pref_restore.getInt("position", -1);

adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, productsGridView, position);

view = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);

view.setAdapter(adapter);

view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(ShowList.this, productsGridView, position);
            view.setAdapter(adapter);

            //Save position to SharedPreferences;
            SharedPreferences pref_save = ShowList.this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref_save.edit();
            editor.putInt("position", position);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

2. Modify ***GridViewAdapter.java***

Modify GridViewAdapter constructor to

```
public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products, int mSelectedPosition)
```

and modify body in getView method like this :

```
holder.productName = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewList1);
if(position == mSelectedPosition){
    holder.productName.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
}
```

3. If you cannot click on item try to set some attribute to your Button that contain in ***listview_values.xml*** :

   ```
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/textViewList1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>
   ```

Comment: it isnt leting me do setAdapter inside the setonItemClickListener

Comment: Sorroy, mAdapter is adapter.

Comment: You cannot use view.setAdapter(); becuase you do not declare it with final.
Try this : **_final GridView view;_**

Comment: that isnt working because when i declare something as final i must initialize it and its value cant be modified and when i initialize it before @OnCreate method it gives an error which makes this not gonna work because i need that variable as global

Comment: Try to see my project sample here : **_http://www.mediafire.com/download/j5rv3775c7hbb5q/MyApplication.rar_**